# is it possible to use ng update to upgrade, but NOT to the latest major version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We're still a little slow and need to upgrade some projects to Angular 7, not yet to 8 (though if it were up to me we would go straight there...).

But this would apply to any future version. When we follow the steps highlighted on the [upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/#6.0:7.2). It forces the latest version of the packages. I can't see a version being specified in the guide commands.

Is it enough to run:

```bsh
ng update @angular/cli@7 @angular/core@7
```

Or is the version of the cli installed globally driving the target? so if we install `@angular/cli@7` globally, it would only attempt to upgrade our project to 7?

Comment: `ng update @angular/core@version` such as `ng update @angular/core@7.0.0`

Comment: Also, you may specify --from=version and --to=version

Comment: @fiveelements so, I am still fuzzy on that `--from` and `--to` option. The documentation seems unclear to me and warns that it only does _migrations_ but does not install that version.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `npm update`? It would do exactly what you want. `ng update` is preferred on major updates because it would adapt your app to new API, meanwhile when doing patch updates there is no major changes in API.

Comment: @EricLiprandi check this option as well `--migrateOnly=true|false`

Answer (score 1):

You can use option --package and --to=to to update to specific version.
Details [here](https://angular.io/cli/update)